# How to write a method that will dynamically search treenodes of a treeview?

Tags: c#, properties

I am creating a (recursive) method that will allow me to specify a root treenode, a treenode property, and a value to match against.

```
SearchAllTreeNodes(rootNode, Tag, "foo");
```

In this example, the intended method would return the `TreeNode` whose `Tag` property matches the string "foo".

I'm not sure how to handle the second argument to the method:

```
public static TreeNode SearchAllTreeNodes(TreeNode rootNode, /* ?? */, string Value)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

How can I specify which property of an object I want to check? Further, is there a recommended way to handle multiple value types or should I simply create some overloads for those (int, bool)?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the answers provided I was able to complete the following method:

```
public static TreeNode SearchAllTreeNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection, Func<TreeNode, bool> match)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in nodeCollection)
    {
        if (match(tn)) return tn;
        if (tn.Nodes.Count <= 0) continue;
        TreeNode f = SearchAllTreeNodes(tn.Nodes, match);
        if (f != null) return f;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Invoked like so:

```
SearchAllTreeNodes(treeView.Nodes, node => node.Tag != null && (string)node.Tag == "foo")
```

or:

```
SearchAllTreeNodes(treeView.Nodes, node => node.Tag != null && (int)node.Tag == 42)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for a delegate (in which you encapsulate the comparison with the desired value):

```
public static TreeNode SearchAllTreeNodes(TreeNode rootNode, Func<TreeNode, bool> match)
{
    if (match(rootNode))
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Invoke:

```
SearchAllTreeNodes(rootNode, node => node.Tag == "foo");
```

Comment: Agreed. You may want to also look at the Visitor design pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this was what got the job done. [(Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) @neontapir Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely learn about this design pattern [(Reference)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers in that you should take a delegate to perform the match, but if you really want to take the approach of specifying a property and value, you can use reflection and specify the the property name as a string:

```
public static TreeNode SearchAllTreeNodes(TreeNode rootNode, string property, string value)
{
  PropertyInfo propertyInfo = treeNode.GetType().GetProperty(property);
  if (propertyInfo.GetValue(treeNode, null).ToString() == value)
  {
    /* Do stuff */
  }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  /* ... */

  SearchAllTreeNodes(someNode, "Tag", "foo");
}
```

Of course, keep in mind that reflection is slow, it would not be recommended to run the above code over a large number of comparisons. You can speed it up by keeping hold of the PropertyInfo object and reusing it, rather obtaining it every time.

Comment: Thanks for this alternate, I was wondering if I would need to use reflection (but wasn't sure of its implementation).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static TreeNode SearchAllTreeNodes(TreeNode rootNode, Func<TreeNode, bool> matchCriteria, string Value)
{
  if (matchCriteria != null ) 
   {
      var result = matchCriteria(rootNode);
   }
}
```